# Alternative to Global Variable or Singleton

Tags: powershell, singleton, global-variables

I have read in various places that Global variables are at best a code smell, and best avoided. At the moment I am working on refactoring a big function based PS script to classes, and thought to use a Singleton. The use case being a large data structure that will need to be referenced from a lot of different classes and modules. 
Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865413/implementing-singleton-inheritable-class-in-c-sharp), which seems to suggest that Singletons are a bad idea too.

So, what IS the right way (in PS 5.1) to create a single data structure that needs to be referenced by a lot of classes, and modified by some of them? Likely pertinent is the fact that I do NOT need this to be thread safe. By definition the queue will be processed in a very linear fashion.

FWIW, I got to the referenced link looking for information on singletons and inheritance, since my singleton is simply one of a number of classes with very similar behavior, where I start with the singleton which contains collections of the next class, which each contain collections of the next class, to create a hierarchical queue. I wanted to have a base class that handled all the common queue management then extend that for the differing functionality lof each class. Which works great other than having that first extended class be a singleton. That seems to be impossible, correct?

EDIT: Alternatively, is it possible with this nested classes in a generic list property approach to be able to identify the parent from within a child? This is how I handled this is the Function based version. A global `[XML]` variable formed the data structure, and I could step through that structure, using `.SelectNode()` to populate a variable to pass to the next function down, and using `.Parent` to get information from higher up, and especially from the root of the data structure.

EDIT: Since I seem not to be able to paste code here right now, I have some code on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/PragmaticPraxis/38cebda38d152db8729f524520a6919c). The example here of where the Singleton comes in is at line 121, where I need to verify if there are any other examples of the same task that have not yet comnepelted, so I can skip all but the last instance. This is a proof of concept for deleting common components of various Autodesk software, which is managed in a very ad hoc manner. So I want to be able to install any mix of programs (packages) and uninstall on any schedule, and ensure that the last package that has a shared component uninstall is the one that uninstalls it. So as to no break other dependent programs before that last uninstall happens. Hopefully that makes sense. Autodesk installs are a fustercluck of misery. If you don't have to deal with them, consider yourself lucky. :)

Comment: It sounds like you _don't_ need a singleton - just create a single instance of your class and operate on that. In any case, your question is almost impossible to give a reasonable answer to - where is the existing code, and _what are you hoping to achieve_ by rewriting using classes?

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, I tried posting some code, but it seems like StackOverflow has a bug at the moment. When I paste the code it it automatically gets identified as code, but only partially formatted. It's enough code it's problematic.

Comment: Regarding the refactor, it's mostly about code reuse. At the task level I have 30 or so different tasks, and a lot of duplicate code in each one. OOP solves that and other problems. Another place I am looking at a singleton is some initialization and status data. I need to keep track of the status (changes, no changes, warnings, errors) so I can rename the final log file based on the final status. Plus there are a number of properties I set at initialization and reference later. A Global Variable/Singleton Class seem like the only way to do that, other than constantly passing on that info.

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, got something hosted on Git Hub now. Formatting isn't great, but better than what I am getting here at the moment.

Comment: I see _nothing_ in your code that requires implementation of a singleton, so I guess the answer is: _stop worrying about it_ :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen So, how would I access the ProcessQueue so I can loop through and check for not yet completed tasks, from within a task? For the life of me I can't see a way to do it without global variable or singleton. No doubt I am about to learn something useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, nothing in the code you linked to requires a singleton.

If you want to retain a parent-child relationship between your `ProcessQueue` and related `Task` instance, that can be solved structurally.

Simply require injection of a `ProcessQueue` instance in the `Task` constructor:

```
class ProcessQueue
{
  hidden [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]$Queue = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::New()
}

class Task
{
  [ProcessQueue]$Parent
  [string]$Id
  Task([string]$id, [ProcessQueue]$parent)
  {
    $this.Parent = $parent
    $this.Id = $id
  }
}
```

When instantiating the object hierarchy:

```
$myQueue = [ProcessQueue]::new()
$myQueue.Add([Task]@{ Id = "id"; Parent = $myQueue})
```

... or refactor `ProcessQueue.Add()` to take care of constructing the task:

```bsh
class ProcessQueue
{
  [Task] Add([string]$Id){
    $newTask = [Task]::new($Id,$this)
    $Queue.Add($newTask)
    return $newTask
  }
}
```

At which point you just use `ProcessQueue.Add()` as a proxy for the `[Task]` constructor:

```
$newTask = $myQueue.Add($id)
$newTask.DisplayName = "Display name goes here"
```

---

Next time you need to search related tasks from a single `Task` instance, you just do:

```
$relatedTasks = $task.Parent.Find($whatever)
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen I will give this a try today. The thing I am not yet understanding is, if I am passing the entire data structure to the task, is that by reference? Since at the task level I need to resolve it, which means updating the task, which is contained in the ProcessQueue. If it works by reference that's grand, because then I could pass in either a parent or a root as needed. So, I guess the question becomes can I force the ProcessQueue to be passed by reference? I am going to give [Ref] a try with fingers crossed.

Comment: You don't need `[ref]` - classes are reference types :)

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, this does beg one last question. Singleton is a very well documented pattern. So I wonder, IS there a time when a Singleton is the right answer in PowerShell? Or is Singleton a pattern that has fallen out of favor? Or PowerShell just isn't a good fit and there are better ways?
And since I will need to pass that reference from `[ProcessQueue]` into all the child `[Set]`s, and those have child `[Package]`s, and all those have child `[Task]`s, and that's where I finally use the passed info. Singleton SEEMS so much easier, which is why I went down this road.

Comment: Singleton's are only useful for providing exclusive resource access to multiple threads within the same process/appdomain. Since you don't require multi-threading of any kind, there's no point in implementing a singleton. For your nested hierarchy, you can repeat the exercise for all classes contained in another class in the hierarchy: inject an expected parent type. That being said, if your `[Task]`'s need to "see" eachother, that's in itself a smell that this object hierarchy you're designing is maybe not really fit for purpose?

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022405/45375) - which may well be the best solution to your problem - with an answer to your original question:

> So, what IS the right way (in PS 5.1) to create a single data structure that needs to be referenced by a lot of classes, and modified by some of them [without concern for thread safety]?

- The main reason that ***global variables* are to be avoided is that they are *session*-global**, meaning that code that executes *after* your own sees those variables too, which can have side effects.
- **You cannot implement a true singleton in PowerShell**, because PowerShell classes do not support *access modifiers*; notably, you cannot make a constructor *private* (non-public), you can only "hide" it with the `hidden` keyword, which merely makes it *less discoverable* while still being *accessible*.
- **You can *approximate* a singleton with the following technique**, which itself emulates a *static class* (which PowerShell also doesn't support, because the `static` keyword is only supported on class *members*, not the class as a whole).

A simple example:

```bash
# NOT thread-safe
class AlmostAStaticClass {
  hidden AlmostAStaticClass() { Throw "Instantiation not supported; use only static members." }
  static [string] $Message    # static property
  static [string] DoSomething() { return ([AlmostAStaticClass]::Message + '!') }
}
```

`[AlmostAStaticClass]::<member>` (e.g., `[AlmostAStaticClass]::Message = 'hi'`) can now be used in the scope in which `AlmostAStaticClass` was defined *and all descendant scopes* (but it is *not* available globally, unless the defining scope happens to be the global one).

If you need access to the class *across module boundaries*, you can pass it as a *parameter* (as a type literal); note that you still need `::` to access the (invariably static) members; e.g.,
`& { param($staticClass) $staticClass::DoSomething() } ([AlmostAStaticClass])`

---

**Implementing a *thread-safe* quasi-singleton** - perhaps for use
with [`ForEach-Object -Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) (v7+) or [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) (v6+, but installable on v5.1) - requires **more work**:

Note:

- *Methods* are then required to get and set what are conceptually properties, because PowerShell doesn't support code-backed property getters and setters as of 7.0 (adding this ability is the subject of [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219)).
- You still need an underlying *property* however, because PowerShell doesn't support *fields*; again the best you can do is to *hide* this property, but it is technically still accessible.

The following **example uses [`System.Threading.Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Monitor)** (which C#'s `lock` statement is based on) to manage thread-safe access to a value; for **managing concurrent adding and removing items from *collections***, use the **[thread-safe collection types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/)** from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

```bash
# Thread-safe
class AlmostAStaticClass {

  static hidden [string] $_message = ''  # conceptually, a *field*
  static hidden [object] $_syncObj = [object]::new() # sync object for [Threading.Monitor]

  hidden AlmostAStaticClass() { Throw "Instantiation not supported; use only static members." }

  static SetMessage([string] $text) {
    Write-Verbose -vb $text
    # Guard against concurrent access by multiple threads.
    [Threading.Monitor]::Enter([AlmostAStaticClass]::_syncObj)
    [AlmostAStaticClass]::_message = $text
    [Threading.Monitor]::Exit([AlmostAStaticClass]::_syncObj)
  }

  static [string] GetMessage() {
    # Guard against concurrent access by multiple threads.
    # NOTE: This only works with [string] values and instances of *value types*
    #       or returning an *element from a collection* that is 
    #       only subject to concurrency in terms of *adding and removing*
    #       elements.
    #       For all other (reference) types - entire (non-concurrent) 
    #       collections or individual objects whose properties are
    #       themselves subject to concurrent access, the *calling* code 
    #       must perform the locking.
    [Threading.Monitor]::Enter([AlmostAStaticClass]::_syncObj)
    $msg = [AlmostAStaticClass]::_message
    [Threading.Monitor]::Exit([AlmostAStaticClass]::_syncObj)
    return $msg
  }

  static [string] DoSomething() { return ([AlmostAStaticClass]::GetMessage() + '!') }
  
}
```

Note that, similar to crossing module boundaries, using threads too requires passing the class as a type object to other threads, which, however is more conveniently done with the `$using:` scope specifier; a simple (contrived) example:

```bash
# !! BROKEN AS OF v7.0
$class = [AlmostAStaticClass]
1..10 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { ($using:class)::SetMessage($_) }
```

**Note**: This cross-thread use is actually **broken as of v7.0**, due to classes currently being tied to the *defining* runspace - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12801). It is to be seen if a solution will be provided.

---

As you can see, the limitations of PowerShell classes make implementing such scenarios cumbersome; using [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) with ad hoc-compiled C# code is worth considering as an alternative.

**This [GitHub meta issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652) is a compilation of various issues relating to PowerShell classes**; while they may eventually get resolved, **it is unlikely that PowerShell's classes will ever reach feature parity with C#**; after all, OOP is not the focus of PowerShell's scripting language (except with respect to *using* preexisting objects).

Comment: I am legit anxiety-sweating at the prospect of ever encountering a code base using this pattern ^_^

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen My primary aim was to shed light on whether and how you can implement a singleton pattern in PowerShell (and in the process shed some light on PowerShell's limitations with respect to OOP / classes). Undoubtedly, it is generally preferable to avoid global data structures. I've added an example of a thread-safe quasi-singleton, but it's clear that both defining such a class and using it in PowerShell are cumbersome.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Turns out that using custom classes across threads with `ForEach-Object` is actually broken as of 7.0 - see  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12801

Comment: OK, this Dependency Injection is starting to make more sense. [See(https://gist.github.com/PragmaticPraxis/cb807c204dbde9e8512c78d373d80326)
Now to try and grok mklement0's multithreaded additions. Not something I need now, but good to understand.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah, I ran into similar recently with a concurrent collection wrapper - more than 4 iterations over `ForEach-Object` and I start losing data